# JSP form on App engine form submission return server Error

Tags: java, html, jsp, google-app-engine, java-web-start

I have deployed my java web app on App engine, my previous version was working, I just make some changes inside HTML & JS files and re-deploy a new version, but now the contact form is not working, it returns this error as:

> **Error: Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

**Here's my JAVA servlet code:**

```
package com.unmundonuevo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UnmundonuevoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        // set credentials
        Sendgrid mail = new Sendgrid("UNAME", "UPASS");
String name=req.getParameter("name");
String email=req.getParameter("email");
String subject=req.getParameter("subject");
String message=req.getParameter("message");

        // set email data
        mail.setTo(email).setFrom("EMAIL").setSubject("Your request has been submitted successfully")
        .setHtml("<strong>Hello " 
                + "!</strong><br><br> We appreciate you contacting us, We will be in touch very soon.<br><br>Thank you <br> Nelly & Sandy");
                
        // send your message
        try {
            mail.send();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        Sendgrid mail1 = new Sendgrid("UNAME", "UPASS");
        
        mail1.setTo("umnsica@gmail.com").setFrom("EMAIL").setSubject("New contact request from http://www.unmundonuevo.school")
        .setText("Hello World!")
        .setHtml("<strong>Hello " 
                + "!</strong>"
                + "<br><br> "+name+" sent a message on unmundonuevo.school. "
                + "<br>Email : " + email +  
                "<br>Subject : " + subject + 
                "<br>Message : "+message+"");
        
        // send your message
                try {
                    mail1.send();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        
        
          PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            
          resp.setContentType("text/html");
          
            resp.setHeader("Refresh", ".1; url=/index.jsp?message=Mail Sent Successfully#contact");
            

    }
}
```

And here's my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Unmundonuevo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.unmundonuevo.UnmundonuevoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Unmundonuevo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/unmundonuevo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here's my HTML form:

```
<!-- Form Starts -->
<div id="contact_form">
   <h4 align="center"  ><font color="#8BC34A"><%if(request.getParameter("message") != null){%><%=request.getParameter("message") %><%} %></font></h4> 
   <form action="unmundonuevo" method="post"  >
         <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Name" required="">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Email ID" required="">
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Subject" required="">
           </div>
     <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required=""></textarea>
      <button type="submit" id="contactform" value="Submit" class="btn center-block">Send message</button>
                
    </form>
</div>
```

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that You need onClick action in button.

Comment: Hi @Rafalsonn, how can I define that? please!

Comment: <button type="submit" id="contactform" value="Submit" class="btn center- 
      block" onClick=(executeAction)>Send message</button>
But im not sure if that's it. Can you support more debug?

Comment: It's actually deployed on App engine, this is the only error I can see here.

Comment: I have tried to change the `web.xml`  `<servlet-class>` to `com.unmundonuevo.UnmundonuevoServlet` now it returns `The requested URL /com.unmundonuevo.UnmundonuevoServlet.java was not found on this server.`